# Как достать данные из <select> и направить в python.EEL

Tags: javascript, python, eel

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background: #c21500;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ffc500, #c21500);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffc500, #c21500); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

.valuta{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: -17px;
    margin-left: 19px;
}

#valuta_1{
    height: 23px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.p_v{
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#valuta_2{
    height: 23px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.input_for{
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

#equals{
    width: 52px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 56px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


#main_name{
    text-align: center;
}

#number_for_konv{
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

#bt{
    margin-left: 83px;
}

#button_main{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#button_main:hover {
    background-color: #fe8952
    }

#button_main:active {
  background-color: #fe8952;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #f59494;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Обменник курсов</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="main_name">Конвертер валют</h1>
    <div class="valuta">
        <p>Выберите валюту</p>
        <select name="valuta_1" id="valuta_1">
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="BYN">BYN</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
        </select>
        <p class="p_v">Выберите валюту</p>
        <select name="valuta_2" id="valuta_2">
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="BYN">BYN</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input_for">
        <form action="../main.py" method="post">
            <p><input id="number_for_konv" type="number" name="number" placeholder="Введите сумму"></p>
            <img id="equals" src="img/equals.png" alt="">
            <p>Итого : <output id="out"></output> </p> 
        </form> 
    </div>

    <div id="bt">
        <button id="button_main" type="submit">Рассчитать</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        let valuta = document.getElementById('valuta');
        let in_s = document.querySelector('#valuta_1');
        let out_s = document.querySelector('#valuta_2');
        document.querySelector("#button_main").onclick = function () {
            eel.get_course(valuta,in_s,out_s)((x) => {
              document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = x;
            });
          }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не разобрался как закинуть сюда python код,но там все нормально.

Comment: В чём проблема? значение так брать ->`let out_s = document.querySelector('#valuta_2').value`